# CSS - background-image property won't show image

Tags: html, css, background-image

```css
.main_banner {
    background-image: url("../images/main_banner.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <heading>
        <title>
            **********
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css" /> 
    </heading>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <!--Navigation Placeholder-->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="main_banner">
            <!--Main Banner-->
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a `div` tag in my HTML assigned a class of `main_banner`.
For some reason, I cannot get my image that is specified in my stylesheet to display.
 I have my main project folder which contains the following: `index.html`, `images` (folder), and `styles` (folder). My image, `main_banner.png`, is located in my `images` folder.

What am I missing?

```
.main_banner {
    background-image: url('../images/main_banner.png');
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you open up your browser's dev tools?

Comment: try with `background-image: url('/images/main_banner.png');` Because `index.html` and `images` folder are in the same level.

Comment: Aaron, I have several errors all stating the same thing:
VM18:123 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users%C2%BEn%C3%9Esktoppersonal_website
isInViewport @ VM18:123
3index.html:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users%C2%BEn%C3%9Esktoppersonal_website

Comment: Andrew Li, I have tried that as well.

Comment: @Ben This is just due to a browser security issue. In order to fix this, the easiest way is to run a local web server in the directory where your index.html is. Check out [this guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) for more information.

Comment: @laptou, I knew it was some kind of security issue, wasn't certain what I needed to do t fix it. I will do as you instructed and let you know if it works.

Comment: @laptou I installed Python and started an HTTP server in my directory that contains my index.html file. It shows running and is processing the GET requests. But It's still not loading my image. I've updated my post with the CSS code I'm using now.

Comment: This is what is showing in my terminal '127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2018 20:18:51] "GET /styles/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2018 20:18:51] code 404, message File not found'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have referenced your style sheet correctly, you will need to specify a width and height in your CSS. The DOM only sees your block elements as empty. Once you give a height and width your image will show up.

```css
.main_banner {
    background: url("../images/main_banner.jpg");
    /*background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/christmas-lights-defocused-background-bokeh-gold-blue-picture-id613518332?k=6&m=613518332&s=612x612&w=0&h=Own5MdgJXjNhFd0YUyED1UP3mQsHeNhfML9F-DQYdYw=");*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            **********
        </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" /> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <!--Navigation Placeholder-->
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="main_banner">
            <!--Main Banner-->
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @peter, I was missing that as well. I am going to spin up a local server to try to fix the security issue that I was seeing in the console.

Comment: I set up my HTTP server locally using Python and I also added in my width and height. Still a blank white page

Comment: @Ben, I have updated my answer with a code snipet. You need to give definitive height dimensions other than `inherit`. Your current code is telling your `.main_banner` block element to inherit the height of whatever is inside of it; which is currently nothing.

Comment: @Ben the important part here, like Peter said, is giving the element a height value. You don't need a server for this part. It's just the style that's rendered by the browser. Either that, or use an `img` tag to simply display the image within the div, rather than the size of the image depending on the size of the div

Comment: I can definitely just use an 'img' tag, which I did initially, but I was trying to work more in my CSS than in my HTML file. For some reason, even after I've specified a height (200px to be exact) and a width of 100%, I'm still not able to view my image

Comment: @Ben, just so we can rule this out; is the image source in the CSS being referenced correctly (filepath)?

Comment: @MikeYoung just to test, I moved my main_banner.png image to the same directory as my index.html file; omitting the directory jump. Still won't display

Comment: @Peter yes, it was. File path goes like this: personal_website > index.html, styles (folder), images (folder). styles (folder) > styles.css. images (folder) > main_banner.png

Comment: @Peter just for the record, I used the URL that MikeYoung put in the code snippet. It worked then. It has something to do with my folders/files

Comment: @Ben, I don't see a code snippet by MikeYoung. One other question, did you perform a hard refresh/clear cache? This will force your client to show the latest changes. (CMD+Shift+R or CTRL+F5)

Comment: @Peter he updated your snippet up top. He updated the URL with a public link. That works if I put it in my url path. Yes I did a hard refresh and still a full blank white page.

Comment: @Peter Update: I think my image may actually be too large or something. I just added a different image with no problem. Same directory

Comment: @Ben, I took a closer look at your code and spotted a few errors. I mimicked your folder structure on my desktop and was able to get the background image to show using your code. Please see my updated code snippet. File size doesn't have anything to do with the image not showing.

Comment: @Peter I think this will do it. Thanks a ton for sticking with me on it! Haven't had this issue before.